# Proof dividing ratio of points on a line

Tags: geometry

I'm thinking about following situation:

Draw a line with two points $B,C$. Let be $X$ a point between $B$ and $C$. I can write $X$ as the following: $x=\lambda_1 \vec b + \lambda_2 \vec c$. Now should be the dividing ratio $\frac{BX}{BC}=-\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}$.

How can I proof that?

I know $\left[BC\right]=\vec b + \lambda ( \vec c - \vec b)$ but I'm not sure if that helps...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You likely want $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1$. Also, check your 'dividing ratio', and see if it makes sense. What happens if $\lambda_2 = 0$? And what is $\lambda_3$?

Comment: I meant $-\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: $X$ is a point on $BC$ if and only if $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1$.

**Hint:** $BC = \vec {c} - \vec {b}$

**Hint:** $BX = OX - OB =?$

Hence, $\frac {BX}{BC} = ??$.